# What are the most notable papers in tropical cyclone research?

Tags: tropical-cyclone, research, literature-request

A quick Google scholar search indicates that 243,000 papers have the words "Tropical Cyclone." While scientific literature is considered valuable (predatory publishing and pseudo-scientific journals excluded), some papers are more important than others.

What are some of the most important, or most cited, papers within hurricane research?

In anticipation of one criticism of the question: 
[Should we allow requests for references?](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1441/should-we-allow-requests-for-references)

Comment: Voted to close as too broad. Add "literature review" or other terms to narrow the search. Look at recent papers and see what papers they cite, etc.

Comment: @mkennedy Literature request and literature review are practically the same thing. But if it appeases you, then fine.